# Computer theory/ automata example help

Tags: automata

Computer Language/Logic Examples?
These are some of the questions i am having within a few chapters of my automata class and would like some help if you could :) Class is online and can be hard to self teach at times, you dont have to answer all or any for that matter, just thought id ask i got a midterm coming up and would like to know how to do these. ¯*(ツ)*/

Λ is not a word but it’s still used in its language? How do I show that there are other CFGs for these languages that do not use Λ-productions.

(ex i) S → aX | bX
 X → a | b | Λ

(ex ii) S → aX | bS | a | b
 X → aX | a | Λ

(ex iii) S → aS | bX
 X → aX | Λ

(ex iv) S → XaX | bX
 X → XaX | XbX | Λ

How would I convert these CFGs to CNF?
 (ex i) S → SS | a

(ex ii) S → aSa | SSa | a

(ex iii) S → aXX
 X → aS | bS | a

(ex iv) E → E + E
 E → E * E
 E → (E)
 E → 7
 The terminals are + * ( ) 7

How would I make a PDA that accepts the same language (given that a CFG makes L then a PDA makes L)
 S → XaaX
 X → aX | bX | Λ

Comment: I suppose that $\Lambda$ denotes the empty word. Then it is a word.

Answer (score 0):

There are online lecture notes which give *algorithms* for getting rid of $\epsilon$ productions ($\epsilon$ is another name for $\Lambda$) and for converting arbitrary grammars into Chomsky normal form. Both are reasonably simple. There is also an algorithm for converting a context-free grammar to a non-deterministic PDA, but if I remember correctly you first have to convert your grammar to Greibach normal form, so it might be better to understand what the language is and come up with a PDA for it directly.

Since you're taking this course online, I think it will be advantageous for you to find useful lecture notes online yourself, as part of your general education. Finding stuff over the internet is extremely useful, and if that's the only thing you get out of this course, you've already benefitted a lot.

I can illustrate the algorithms by solving some of your examples. In order to eliminate $\epsilon$-productions from your (i), the idea is that for every production that has $X$ in it, we create another one in which $X$ is missing. So we add productions $S \to a | b$. This works in general, but has to be applied iteratively.

In order to convert your (i) to Chomsky normal form, we only need to "rename" $S$: replace $S \to SS$ with $S \to TT$, and add $T \to TT|a$. Other cases require other operations; for example, if you had $A \to BCD$ then you would replace it with $A \to ED$ and $E \to BC$; and if you had $A \to Bc$ then you would replace it with $A \to BC$ and $C \to c$. This should be enough for you to work out the other parts of this question.